# Создать, заполнить и передать массив в php на jQuery.

Tags: jquery, php

Добрый день.В php уже есть массив вида
<pre>
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 127
            [COUNT] => 1
        )

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [ID] => 125
        [COUNT] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [ID] => 123
        [COUNT] => 1
    )
```

)</pre>
На страничке с такой версткой http://jsfiddle.net/Mgk5X/1/ не получается написать скрипт формирующий массив такой же как в php. Даже просто массив не передаёт. Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для массива лучше такой синтаксис:

```
var mas = [5,"uuuh!",7];
```

Но это конечно не влияет на результат. Всё должно работать, если указан правильный путь и отменено стандартное действие после клика по ссылке. Попробуйте записать так:

```
$("a.refresh").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        // дальше всё без изменений
```

Забыл сказать про создание массива.

```
var mas = [5,"uuuh!",7],
    num = parseInt($(".input_qty > input").val(),10),
    totalVals = {};        
for(var i = 0; i < mas.length; i++){
    totalVals[i] = {
        ID: mas[i],
        COUNT: num
    };
}
console.log(totalVals); // смотрим результат в консоли
```

Comment: С квадратными стал работать, а как мне собрать массив? Я не понимаю как мне по всем пройти каунтам и адешникам.

Comment: @Роман20, уже дополнил комментом выше

Comment: Спасибо, скоро вернусь, буду пробовать. О результатах отпишусь)